# json string to filtter in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, metadata

i have audio file meta-data details like blow json string. here i need to filter album and artist based songs. now i am using for loop to filter list but i have more then 2000 unique songs. can i do any other way to do this using nodejs.

```
[{
 "title":"Kallu Kollam - TamilWire.com",
 "picture":"Kallu Kollam - TamilWire.com",
 "artist":["N.D.Rajkumar"],
 "album":"Madhubaanakadai",
 "year":"2012",
 "path":"/media/data/songs/MadhuBana Kadai/Kallu Kollam - TamilWire.com.mp3"
 },
 {"title":"Manjal Nira Bodhai - TamilWire.com",
  "picture":"Manjal Nira Bodhai - TamilWire.com",
  "artist":["N.D.Rajkumar"],
  "album":"Madhubaanakadai",
  "year":"2012",
  "path":"/media/data/songs/MadhuBana Kadai/Manjal Nira Bodhai - TamilWire.com.mp3"}, 
 .....]
```

Comment: Store them in associative arrays as "indexes" so that it's only necessary to loop through the entire array to build the structure and to perform other searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group data by album using underscore library:

```
 var _ = require('underscore');

 var songs = [{
 "title":"Kallu Kollam - TamilWire.com",
 "picture":"Kallu Kollam - TamilWire.com",
 "artist":["N.D.Rajkumar"],
 "album":"Madhubaanakadai",
 "year":"2012",
 "path":"/media/data/songs/MadhuBana Kadai/Kallu Kollam - TamilWire.com.mp3"
 },
 {"title":"Manjal Nira Bodhai - TamilWire.com",
  "picture":"Manjal Nira Bodhai - TamilWire.com",
  "artist":["N.D.Rajkumar"],
  "album":"Madhubaanakadai",
  "year":"2012",
  "path":"/media/data/songs/MadhuBana Kadai/Manjal Nira Bodhai - TamilWire.com.mp3"} 
 ];

 var grouped = _.groupBy(songs, function(song) {return song.album;});
```

Where grouped will be:

```
{
    "Madhubaanakadai": [{ 
            "title":"Kallu Kollam - TamilWire.com", 
            ... 
        }, {
            "title":"Manjal Nira Bodhai - TamilWire.com"
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks.. but here i don't know the album name or any other details.

Comment: what i need get same song.album is it possible

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer to group data by albums. Is this what you wanted?